# Brightness keeps changing (MSI PE60 2QE)

Tags: laptop, brightness, 22.04, msi

I am struggling with an issue with Ubuntu. The screen brightness keeps changing and it seems to happens after I change it. For example, I lower the screen brightness by one step and a couple of seconds later, my screen goes several steps lower or several steps higher. It is very annoying.
My laptop is a MSI PE60 2QE, running Ubuntu 22.04 LTS with Budgie.

I have seen that this isn't a new problem and I have tried the following:

- Disabling automatic brightness: my laptop does not have automatic brightness
- Update BIOS: I updated it, issue still persists

I don't know if it is linked but I have also noticed that my laptop takes a minute to know if it has been plugged in or unplugged.

Does anyone have an idea what I could do to fix this brightness issue ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the content of `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` change also? Is your laptop permanently connected to AC power?

Comment: Check my second answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding the following to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-quirks.conf`:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "Spooky Ghosts"
  MatchProduct "Video Bus"
  Option "Ignore" "on"
  EndSection
```

[SOURCE](https://super-unix.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-random-event-changes-screen-brightness-automatically/)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `/etc/default/grub` using `gedit` or any other text editor.

Find the below line.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

Change the above line to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

This would ensure to load of device-specific drivers before default drivers in Linux.

Save the file and close the text editor.
Open the terminal and run the below command.

```
update-grub
```

Then

```
reboot
```

Comment: Issue still persists, unfortunately. 